# Filter Rad grid on text box TextChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to filter a rad grid on the basis on a text box text change in ASP.Net C#, like when user enter B in text box grid should filter on a column say Employee name which starts with B. I tried something like follow.
 My C# Code

```
 protected void txtSearchName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dtUserDetails = new DataTable();           
                DataView dvStores = new DataView(dtEmployeeDetail);
                dvStores.RowFilter = "EmployeeName LIKE '" + txtSearchName.Text + "%'";
                rgEmployeeDetail.DataSource = dvStores;                                
        }
```

here dtEmployeeDetail is table which contain all data with EmployeeName column

my text box and grid in asp page is as follow

```
    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtSearchName" runat="server" DisplayText="Search" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtSearchName_TextChanged">
                                        </telerik:RadTextBox>
Grid

<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgEmployeeDetail" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" ShowGroupPanel="false"
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize="20" EnableAriaSupport="true" OnItemCommand="rgEmployeeDetail_ItemCommand"
                                    OnNeedDataSource="rgEmployeeDetail_NeedDataSource" OnInit="rgEmployeeDetail_Init">                                   
                                    <MasterTableView Width="100%" TableLayout="Fixed">
                                        <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="true" ShowPagerText="False" PageSizeLabelText="" Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" />
                                        <Columns>
                                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" Visible="false">
                                                <HeaderStyle Width="25%" />
                                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="UserID" HeaderText="Global Id">
                                                <HeaderStyle Width="25%" />
                                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="EmployeeName" HeaderText="Employee Name">
                                                <HeaderStyle Width="50%" />
                                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Extension Number" HeaderText="Extension Number">
                                                <HeaderStyle Width="25%" />
                                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                        </Columns>

                                        <EditFormSettings>
                                            <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column">
                                            </EditColumn>
                                        </EditFormSettings>
                                    </MasterTableView>
                                    <ClientSettings AllowKeyboardNavigation="true">
                                        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" EnableDragToSelectRows="true" />
                                    </ClientSettings>
                                    <PagerStyle PageSizeLabelText="" ShowPagerText="False" />
                                    <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False">
                                    </FilterMenu>
                                </telerik:RadGrid>
```

but its not working grid is not getting filtered as per new Dataview.

Answer (score 0):

Please check ... Are you missing calling rgEmployeeDetail.DataBind()  after the below line
rgEmployeeDetail.DataSource = dvStores;

If this not solved .. please EnableLinqExpressions = false on rad grid and check

Comment: I tried that also but No result. That gives exception No property or field 'EmployeeName' exists in type 'DataRowView'

Comment: That means dtEmployeeDetail table has a different column name other that 'EmployeeName' Please check the column name once again and use that in your RowFilter

Comment: The dataview which it returns have columns exactly same as the data table which I bound to grid. There is no issue in data view column.

Comment: edited the answer please try that one too.. ( EnableLinqExpressions = false ) on designer it self

Comment: That doesnt work I am also using telerik:RadAjaxPanel. All the controls are in that.

Comment: Good to hear .. if that worked please mark the question as answered . good luck ..